# Read data from DVD with maximum speed

Tags: c, winapi, dd, dvd, disk-io

I'm trying to make a disk dump program (like dd) with C language on Windows.
The program is almost finished, but there is one problem: reading data from DVD is very slow.
According to the specification, the DVD drive of my PC supports up to 8x reading rate, but my program reads about 5MB/sec (about 4x). I want to read data with maximum speed.

The algorithm of my program is simple: using win32api CreateFile and ReadFile, like

```
src=CreateFileA("\\\\.\\E:",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
ReadFile(src,buf,buffer_size,&read_ret,NULL);
```

The buffer size can be set to 20-100MB. I tried to set speed with DeviceIoControl, like

```
cdromSetSpeed.RequestType = CdromSetSpeed;
cdromSetSpeed.ReadSpeed = 0xFFFF; // max speed
cdromSetSpeed.WriteSpeed = 0xFFFF; // max speed
cdromSetSpeed.RotationControl = CdromDefaultRotation;
DeviceIoControl(src,IOCTL_CDROM_SET_SPEED,&cdromSetSpeed,sizeof(cdromSetSpeed),NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
```

but it had no effect.

Please tell me if there is any way to read data from DVD with maximum speed.

Comment: If the speed is set correctly, there may be an optimum buffer size to use. There may be an API call to determine this. If not [or maybe even _if_ there _is_ such an API call], you may want to experiment with various buffer sizes (e.g. some multiple of 4096). It could be something like 64KB or 1MB or some other value. See if that has any effect. Otherwise, double check the speed setting code. There may be a call to get back the actual/current speed. You may want to do that after setting it, to see what speed it's _actually_ using [trust--but verify ;-)]. The brochure may overstate things ...

Comment: The DVD read call _may_ be _blocking_ [and likewise with a write call to disk]. You may need to see if there is an asynchronous option [or event driven]. Or, you may need to put the reader code in a separate thread from the writer code. Or, you may need to tell the system that you want continuous/sequential reading (e.g. it won't try to stop the DVD drive because it thinks you're reading sporadically). You may have to use multiple buffers and pass them back and forth between the two threads. That is, you start the _next_ read immediately, and don't wait for the writer to complete

Comment: In fact, to help isolate the problem, tempoarily disable any processing or writing code that is not strictly necessary for reading. Keep this disabled until you get full read speed. This will tell you if the writing code is part of the problem.

Comment: Does your drive operate in [constant angular velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_angular_velocity) mode by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried to use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` asynchronous mode reading or `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` to read sequentially